# Django filter queryset __in=list for *every* item in queryset

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

Let's say I have the following models

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    skills_required = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)

class Skill(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, primary_key=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

How can I filter `Offer.objects` with an instance of `UserProfile` in a way that `skills_required` of remaining offers would be a subset of `user_profile.skills`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count the number of required skills for that offer, and check if the number of skills is equal to the number of skills for that userprofile with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q

Offer.objects.alias(
    req_skill=Count('skills_required', distinct=True),
    skills=Count(
        'skills_required',
        filter=Q(skills_required__userprofile=my_userprofile),
        distinct=True
    )
).filter(
    req_skill=F('skills')
)
```

For Django prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you should use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) instead of [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias).